# How to use JSON class as a inner class instead of seprate class

Tags: apex, webservices, json, code

Main Class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/cases/*')
global with sharing class InsertCaseHelper {
    global static string  responsePayLoad;

    @HTTPPOST  
    global static void insertCase(){
        RestRequest req;
        RestResponse res;
        String jsonPayLoad;  
        try{ 

            req = RestContext.request;
            res = RestContext.response;
            jsonPayLoad=req.requestBody.toString();
            responsePayLoad=jsonPayLoad;
            CaseJsonParser obj=CaseJsonParser.parse(jsonPayLoad);

            if(!String.isBlank(responsePayLoad)){   //check json is blank 

                    List<recordtype> recrodtypeList;
                        recrodtypeList=[select recordtype.id from recordtype where recordtype.name=:obj.cse.recTypeId limit 1]; 
                    if(recrodtypeList.size() > 0) {  

                        case  Newcase=new case();                
                        System.debug('inside IF::');
                        Newcase.status=obj.cse.Status;
                        Newcase.Origin=obj.cse.Origin;
                        Newcase.RecordTypeId=recrodtypeList[0].Id;
                        Newcase.For_a_Business_or_Residential_Customer__c=obj.cse.customerType;
                        Newcase.Reason_for_Completing_this_AIM__c=obj.cse.reasonForCompletingAIM;
                        Newcase.Service_Id__c=obj.cse.serviceId;

                                Insert Newcase; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        createExceptionLog(system.label.Recordtype_Error,'400');

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                createExceptionLog(system.label.Blank_Payload,'400');
            }       
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //createExceptionLog(system.Label.Recordtype_Error,400, System.Label.Failed_To_Process_Request,jsonPayLoad);            
            createExceptionLog(String.valueOf(e),'500');

        }       
    }

    public static void createExceptionLog(String errorMessage, string errorCode){
        String [] ExceptionLog  = new String [] {'Source_Name__c',
            'Destination_System__c','End_Point_URL__c','HTTP_Status_Code__c','Interface_Name__c','Status__c',
            'Correlation_ID__c','Error_Description__c'};
        Exception_Log__c ex1 = new Exception_Log__c();        
        ex1.Source_Name__c = 'AIMS';

            insert ex1; 
    }
}
```

## JSON Cls:

```
   public class CaseJsonParser {

    public  cls_case cse;

    public class cls_case {
        public string status;
        public string Origin;
        public string recTypeId;
        public string customerType;
        public string reasonForCompletingAIM;
        public string serviceId;
        public string enquiryType;


    }

    Public static CaseJsonParser parse(string json){
        return (CaseJsonParser) System.JSON.deserialize(json, CaseJsonParser.class); 
    }

}
```

Instead of this requirement is to create inner Jsonclass under main class.Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Just put the class inside the other class, and move the inner class and static methods outside of the class, like this:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/cases/*')
global with sharing class InsertCaseHelper {
  public class CaseJsonParser {
    public  cls_case cse;
  }
  public class cls_case {
    ...
  }
  Public static CaseJsonParser parse(string json){
    return (CaseJsonParser) System.JSON.deserialize(json, CaseJsonParser.class); 
  }
  @HTTPPOST  
  global static void insertCase(){
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error  "Inner types are not allowed to have inner types "

Comment: @tarun You need to move all inner stuff outside. I updated my answer to reflect this.